# Loose translation of last name?

Tags: meaning, onomastics

I was told that “Altenbaugh” is loosely translated as old tree, or something like that. Is that accurate?

Comment: Translations of last names is sometimes not really possible. My last name is _Makulik_ and probably some polish / slawonian root, though there's no real meaningful _"translation"_. The closest we got with research of some of my family members was "Mohnbauer", but there was no certain source for nailing onto that.

Comment: urbandictionary says Baugh is "A Celtic surname that comes from the Welsh word "bach" for tiny."

Comment: I think that name was *Altenbach* initially but as English speakers had problems pronouncing the German *-bach*, one of the ancestors replaced it with *-baugh* which is an English version of the Welsh *-bach*. So the meaning was *old creek* initially.

Comment: The problem is that there was a time when most people did not know how to spell their own name. So the first recorded spelling is a guess. People could have used the same spelling  *baugh* for people with different origins, either Germanic or Celtic, as there are plausible etymologies either way. If it is Celtic it could be Altbeg (small stream in Scots Gaelic) which actually exists in more than one place, see [here](https://www.zoopla.co.uk/property/altbeg/corriegills/isle-of-arran/ka27-8bl/28647516) and [here](https://www.zoopla.co.uk/property/altbeg/corsee-road/banchory/ab31-5rt/122486).

Comment: But to explain the -en- you could easily have a diminutive *Alltan Beag* (modern spelling with -ag shows match to *baugh*) "small little stream". Or you could insert a definite article. "Stream of the birches" seems highly plausible on the model of [Ellenabeich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellenabeich). But at the end of the day you need more information to determine if Celtic or Germanic is more likely.

Comment: I'm under the impression that Onomastics is a bit like reading tea leaves, if names are prone to corruption, or rather seeing figures in the stars. There are just too many, they change place a lot, and some come from too far away. (Adding something constructive:) *Bauch* (belly) would work, if it's an anatomic name, and alt may mean *big, grown*; Because *gh* does correlate with *ch* often enough (e.g. *light, licht*), though perhaps not after *o* or *au*

Comment: @vectory Do you know any German surname that contains _Bauch_ though?

Comment: Well, it seems "old belly" is more likely :-) Tree would be "Baum" on German. "Baum" and "Baugh" sounds too differently on German, my non-native speaker insight is that "Baugh" probably would not transform to "Baum" in the centuries. But a "Baugh" -> "Bauch" transform is realistic.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to answer this question without knowing the place where this name occurs.

Regarding German words, then only the first half is translatable: "Alten" is a form of "alt" and means in deed "old". But "baugh" has no german equivalent.

But (inspired by the comments) I also found a [website](https://www.houseofnames.com) which gives detailed explanations of names. Unfortunately the whole name "Altenbaugh" can not be found, but its two halves. According to this website

- "alten" comes from the Old English awiell, which means *enclosure* or *settlement*.
- "baugh" was initally a nickname for a small or short man, derived from the Welsh word "bach," which means "little".

So in conclusion it seems that the surename "Altenbaugh" can loosely be translated as "**tiny settlement**".

Comment: "awiell" means 'spring', and "tun" means enclosure or settlement

Answer (score 3):

The person who told you that simply guessed that "*alten*" is German (and means *old*) and that *baugh* might be related to German *Baum* (=*tree*).

I think that the person is right with *alten*, but I would be surprised, if German "*Baum*" had changed to "*-baugh*". Like *Janka* and others I priviledge another word as source: *Bach* (in German) or *beek* (in Dutch) which could have become "-baugh" after anglicisation. The name would mean something like "old creek".

Today there exist at least two *Altenbach* in Germany (in Saxony and Baden-Wurttemberg). A Saxon settlement in England could have been named the same and become "Altenbaugh" in the course of time.
It's also possibly that a German immigrant with name *Altenbach* is at the origin of the surname *Altenbaugh*.

(This is my guess, which is only slightly better than what the person told you.)

Answer (score 0):

"Alten" has various meanings but when combined with other words it has a more specific meaning. For a name such as "Altenbach" the word "Alten" means "the origin or source" of "bach" or the origin of a river, which is where the beginning of a stream is located. Most commonly a stream begins in the mountains. "Baugh" is not a form nor a derivation of "Altenbach". However, the same approach could be taken to understand its meaning if you know how "baugh" translates. However, this word appears to be imported into Germany for which there could be a multitude of translations. Someone with this namesake should come forth to clarify their family's understanding of it.